# How to integrate Wikidata query in python

Tags: python, sparql, wikidata-query-service

I am currently using [Wikidata Query Service](https://query.wikidata.org/) to run my Wikidata queries.

For example, one of my Wikidata queries looks as follows.

```
SELECT ?sLabel {
    SERVICE wikibase:mwapi {
        bd:serviceParam wikibase:api "EntitySearch".
        bd:serviceParam wikibase:endpoint "www.wikidata.org".
        bd:serviceParam mwapi:search "natural language processing".
        bd:serviceParam mwapi:language "en".
        ?item wikibase:apiOutputItem mwapi:item.
        ?num wikibase:apiOrdinal true.
    }
    ?s wdt:P279|wdt:P31 ?item .
    SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en" }
}
ORDER BY ?num
LIMIT 10
```

I would like to know if we can use these queries in a python program? If so, how can we integrate the queries in python?

I am happy to provide more details if needed.

Comment: it's not allowed to ask for tool, libs etc. on Stackoverflow, or better said it's considered off-topic. And using a seach engine for "Python + SPARQL" should show up `sparqlwrapper` as part of `RDFlib` as one of the first hits.

Comment: @AKSW Wasn't aware of it before. Thank you and noted :)

Comment: Tool requests are welcome at https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`sparqlwrapper` can handle that. You can find more information [here](https://people.wikimedia.org/~bearloga/notes/wdqs-python.html)

Answer (score 12):

In case you want to do it without a SPARQL specific library:

```
import requests

url = 'https://query.wikidata.org/sparql'
query = '''
SELECT ?item ?itemLabel ?linkcount WHERE {
    ?item wdt:P31/wdt:P279* wd:Q35666 .
    ?item wikibase:sitelinks ?linkcount .
FILTER (?linkcount >= 1) .
SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en" . }
}
GROUP BY ?item ?itemLabel ?linkcount
ORDER BY DESC(?linkcount)
'''
r = requests.get(url, params = {'format': 'json', 'query': query})
data = r.json()
```

Comment: can you please add code to convert to data.frame

Comment: see my answer below - the list of dicts can be directly imported to pandas

Comment: @userJT here is some "how to" including using Panda https://itnext.io/extracting-data-from-wikidata-using-sparql-and-python-59e0037996f

Answer (score -2):

As the committer of http://wiki.bitplan.com/index.php/PyLoDStorage i'd recommend this library since it wraps sparqlwrapper in a way that you immediately get proper python types. Thus you'll be able to get the data into other libaries such as pandas or work with csv, json, xml, sql or whatever your followup needs are.

I have modified and extended your query a bit

```
# WF 2021-10-30
# see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55961615/how-to-integrate-wikidata-query-in-python/69771615#69771615
SELECT ?s ?sLabel ?item ?itemLabel ?sourceCode ?webSite ?stackexchangeTag  {
    SERVICE wikibase:mwapi {
        bd:serviceParam wikibase:api "EntitySearch".
        bd:serviceParam wikibase:endpoint "www.wikidata.org".
        bd:serviceParam mwapi:search "natural language processing".
        bd:serviceParam mwapi:language "en".
        ?item wikibase:apiOutputItem mwapi:item.
        ?num wikibase:apiOrdinal true.
    }
    ?s wdt:P279|wdt:P31 ?item .
    OPTIONAL { 
      ?s wdt:P1324 ?sourceCode.
    }
    OPTIONAL {    
      ?s wdt:P856 ?webSite.
    }
    OPTIONAL {    
      ?s wdt:P1482 ?stackexchangeTag.
    }
    SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en" }
}
ORDER BY ?itemLabel ?sLabel
```

[try it!](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20%3Fs%20%3FsLabel%20%3Fitem%20%3FitemLabel%20%3FsourceCode%20%3FwebSite%20%3FstackexchangeTag%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Amwapi%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Aapi%20%22EntitySearch%22.%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Aendpoint%20%22www.wikidata.org%22.%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20bd%3AserviceParam%20mwapi%3Asearch%20%22natural%20language%20processing%22.%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20bd%3AserviceParam%20mwapi%3Alanguage%20%22en%22.%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fitem%20wikibase%3AapiOutputItem%20mwapi%3Aitem.%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fnum%20wikibase%3AapiOrdinal%20true.%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Fs%20wdt%3AP279%7Cwdt%3AP31%20%3Fitem%20.%0A%20%20%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fs%20wdt%3AP1324%20%3FsourceCode.%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fs%20wdt%3AP856%20%3FwebSite.%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fs%20wdt%3AP1482%20%3FstackexchangeTag.%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22%5BAUTO_LANGUAGE%5D%2Cen%22%20%7D%0A%7D%0AORDER%20BY%20%3FitemLabel%20%3FsLabel%0A)

and then used it as a showcase for the pyLoDStorage library:

```py
def testStackoverflow55961615Query(self):
        '''
        see 
        https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55961615/how-to-integrate-wikidata-query-in-python
        https://stackoverflow.com/a/69771615/1497139
        '''
        endpoint="https://query.wikidata.org/sparql"
        wd=SPARQL(endpoint)
        queryString="""SELECT ?s ?sLabel ?item ?itemLabel ?sourceCode ?webSite ?stackexchangeTag  {
    SERVICE wikibase:mwapi {
        bd:serviceParam wikibase:api "EntitySearch".
        bd:serviceParam wikibase:endpoint "www.wikidata.org".
        bd:serviceParam mwapi:search "natural language processing".
        bd:serviceParam mwapi:language "en".
        ?item wikibase:apiOutputItem mwapi:item.
        ?num wikibase:apiOrdinal true.
    }
    ?s wdt:P279|wdt:P31 ?item .
    OPTIONAL { 
      ?s wdt:P1324 ?sourceCode.
    }
    OPTIONAL {    
      ?s wdt:P856 ?webSite.
    }
    OPTIONAL {    
      ?s wdt:P1482 ?stackexchangeTag.
    }
    SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en" }
}
ORDER BY ?itemLabel ?sLabel"""
        qlod=wd.queryAsListOfDicts(queryString,fixNone=True)
        query=Query(name="EntitySearch",query=queryString,lang='sparql')
        debug=self.debug
        for tablefmt in ["github","mediawiki","latex"]:
            lod=copy.deepcopy(qlod)
            qdoc=query.documentQueryResult(lod,tablefmt=tablefmt)
            if debug:
                print (qdoc)
```

And the output could be pasted here immediately as shown below. The output is also available in any format supported by the [tabulate library](https://pypi.org/project/tabulate/) such as mediawiki, latex and others.

### EntitySearch

#### query

```sql
SELECT ?s ?sLabel ?item ?itemLabel ?sourceCode ?webSite ?stackexchangeTag  {
    SERVICE wikibase:mwapi {
        bd:serviceParam wikibase:api "EntitySearch".
        bd:serviceParam wikibase:endpoint "www.wikidata.org".
        bd:serviceParam mwapi:search "natural language processing".
        bd:serviceParam mwapi:language "en".
        ?item wikibase:apiOutputItem mwapi:item.
        ?num wikibase:apiOrdinal true.
    }
    ?s wdt:P279|wdt:P31 ?item .
    OPTIONAL { 
      ?s wdt:P1324 ?sourceCode.
    }
    OPTIONAL {    
      ?s wdt:P856 ?webSite.
    }
    OPTIONAL {    
      ?s wdt:P1482 ?stackexchangeTag.
    }
    SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en" }
}
ORDER BY ?itemLabel ?sLabel
```

### result

| s | sLabel | item | itemLabel | stackexchangeTag | sourceCode | webSite |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q24841819 | Q24841819 | http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q30642 | natural language processing |  |  |  |
| http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q1898737 | Morphological analysis | http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q30642 | natural language processing |  |  |  |
| http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q6913444 | Morphological parsing | http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q30642 | natural language processing |  |  |  |
| http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q104415642 | Wikification | http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q30642 | natural language processing |  |  |  |
| http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q51751772 | biomedical natural language processing | http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q30642 | natural language processing |  |  |  |
| http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q46346005 | computer-based question classification | http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q30642 | natural language processing |  |  |  |
| http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q1513879 | natural language generation | http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q30642 | natural language processing | https://stackoverflow.com/tags/nlg |  |  |
| http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q1078276 | natural language understanding | http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q30642 | natural language processing |  |  |  |
| http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q1271424 | part-of-speech tagging | http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q30642 | natural language processing |  |  |  |
| http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q105171570 | speaker verification | http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q30642 | natural language processing |  |  |  |
| http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q189436 | speech recognition | http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q30642 | natural language processing | https://ai.stackexchange.com/tags/speech-recognition |  |  |
| http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q189436 | speech recognition | http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q30642 | natural language processing | https://cs.stackexchange.com/tags/speech-recognition |  |  |
| http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q189436 | speech recognition | http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q30642 | natural language processing | https://dsp.stackexchange.com/tags/speech-recognition |  |  |
| http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q189436 | speech recognition | http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q30642 | natural language processing | https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/tags/speech-recognition |  |  |
| http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q189436 | speech recognition | http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q30642 | natural language processing | https://stackoverflow.com/tags/speech-recognition |  |  |
| http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q189436 | speech recognition | http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q30642 | natural language processing | https://unix.stackexchange.com/tags/speech-recognition |  |  |
| http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q1948408 | text segmentation | http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q30642 | natural language processing |  |  |  |
| http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q3484781 | text simplification | http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q30642 | natural language processing |  |  |  |
| http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q2438971 | tokenization | http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q30642 | natural language processing |  |  |  |
| http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q105330879 | word segmentation | http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q30642 | natural language processing |  |  |  |
| http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q7095836 | Apache OpenNLP | http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q21129801 | natural language processing toolkit | https://stackoverflow.com/tags/opennlp | http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/opennlp | http://opennlp.apache.org |
| http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q7095836 | Apache OpenNLP | http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q21129801 | natural language processing toolkit | https://stackoverflow.com/tags/opennlp | https://github.com/apache/opennlp | http://opennlp.apache.org |
| http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q7095836 | Apache OpenNLP | http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q21129801 | natural language processing toolkit | https://stackoverflow.com/tags/opennlp | https://github.com/apache/opennlp.git | http://opennlp.apache.org |
| http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q7095836 | Apache OpenNLP | http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q21129801 | natural language processing toolkit | https://stackoverflow.com/tags/opennlp | http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/opennlp | https://opennlp.apache.org/ |
| http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q7095836 | Apache OpenNLP | http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q21129801 | natural language processing toolkit | https://stackoverflow.com/tags/opennlp | https://github.com/apache/opennlp | https://opennlp.apache.org/ |
| http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q7095836 | Apache OpenNLP | http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q21129801 | natural language processing toolkit | https://stackoverflow.com/tags/opennlp | https://github.com/apache/opennlp.git | https://opennlp.apache.org/ |
| http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q975453 | General Architecture for Text Engineering | http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q21129801 | natural language processing toolkit |  | https://github.com/GateNLP | http://gate.ac.uk |
| http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q5533567 | Gensim | http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q21129801 | natural language processing toolkit |  | https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim | https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/ |
| http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q48688669 | LingPipe | http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q21129801 | natural language processing toolkit | https://stackoverflow.com/tags/lingpipe |  | http://alias-i.com/lingpipe/ |
| http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q6553971 | LinguaStream | http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q21129801 | natural language processing toolkit |  |  |  |
| http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q5396532 | MALLET | http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q21129801 | natural language processing toolkit |  |  | http://mallet.cs.umass.edu/ |
| http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q6906675 | MontyLingua | http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q21129801 | natural language processing toolkit |  |  | [http://web.media.mit.edu/~hugo/montylingua/](http://web.media.mit.edu/%7Ehugo/montylingua/) |
| http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q3630063 | Moses | http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q21129801 | natural language processing toolkit |  | https://github.com/moses-smt/mosesdecoder | http://www.statmt.org/moses |
| http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q1635410 | Natural Language Toolkit | http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q21129801 | natural language processing toolkit | https://stackoverflow.com/tags/nltk | https://github.com/nltk/nltk | http://nltk.org/ |
| http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q17071870 | NiuTrans | http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q21129801 | natural language processing toolkit |  |  | http://www.nlplab.com/NiuPlan/NiuTrans.html |
| http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q47405152 | Pattern | http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q21129801 | natural language processing toolkit |  | https://github.com/clips/pattern | http://www.clips.ua.ac.be/pages/pattern |
| http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q32998961 | Stanford CoreNLP | http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q21129801 | natural language processing toolkit |  |  | https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/ |
| http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q104840874 | Stanza | http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q21129801 | natural language processing toolkit |  | https://stanfordnlp.github.io/stanza/ | https://stanfordnlp.github.io/stanza/ |
| http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q2593410 | WordSmith | http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q21129801 | natural language processing toolkit |  |  | http://www.lexically.net |

```sh
test testStackoverflow55961615Query, debug=False took   0.5 s
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.503s

OK
```